# Using regex_replace in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have got a variable test with this value 
`D:\\Scripts\\Exports\\VM_State_201907161157.csv`

I want to replace all `"\\"` with `"\"` so the final result should be `D:\Scripts\Exports\VM_State_201907161157.csv`

How can I do that with regex_replace in ansible:-

```
  - set_fact:
       test2: "{{ test | regex_replace() }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [7.3.2. Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097)

> The single-quoted style is specified by surrounding “'” indicators. Therefore, within a single-quoted scalar, such characters need to be repeated. This is the only form of escaping performed in single-quoted scalars. In particular, the “\” and “"” characters may be freely used. ...

The tasks below

```
  vars:
    # string1: 'D:\\Scripts\\Exports\\VM_State_201907161157.cs'
    string1: 'D:\\Scr'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: string1|list
    - set_fact:
        string2: |-
          {{ string1|regex_replace( '\\\\', '\\' ) }}
    - debug:
        var: string2|list
```

give (strings transformed to lists to see the elements)

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "string1|list": [
        "D", 
        ":", 
        "\\", 
        "\\", 
        "S", 
        "c", 
        "r"
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "string2|list": [
        "D", 
        ":", 
        "\\", 
        "S", 
        "c", 
        "r"
    ]
}
```

It is also possible to compare the strings in a file created from the template

```
string1: {{ string1 }}
string2: {{ string2 }}
```

which gives

```
string1: D:\\Scr
string2: D:\Scr
```

Comment: It still gives output as "\\" , how can it be changed to "\"?

Comment: be aware "\\" is like '\'